# Favicon.ico not being requested

Tags: html, node.js, ico

Is there a way to setup an icon for an HTML page using only 'http' and 'fs' modules for node.js (without express)?

I have index.html, main_page.css and favicon.ico files in my directory.

When the client connects, it receives index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Site</title>
  <link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main_page.css" />
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Then the server receives a request for .css file and sends it to the client.

The page is styled as it should be, so there is no reason to show the code.

The question is, why does the client ask for .css file by itself and doesn't ask for .ico?

This is the code on the server, that serves the files:

```
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');

http.createServer(function(req, res) {
  switch (req.url) {
    case '/': {
      get_file('index.html', res);
      break;
    }
    case '/css/main_page.css': {
      get_file('css/main_page.css',res);
      break;
    }
    case '/favicon.ico': {
      get_file('favicon.ico', res);
      break;
    }
    default: {
      res.statusCode = 404;
      res.end("Not found");
    }
  }
}).listen(8081);

function get_file(path, res) {
//dont mind my ROOT ;0
  fs.readFile(ROOT + path, function(err, content) {
    if(err) {
      console.log(err.message);
    } else {
      console.log(path);
      res.end(content);
    }
  })
}
```

Comment: I just tested the HTML file in Chrome, and the `ico` file definitely shows up as a request from the client under the network tab.

Comment: Sure it is. But not with Node.js server. This html works perfectly for me using php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `favicon.ico` file gets cached by Chrome, so once it has been requested once, it will not be requested again until the cache expires. To generate a new request for `favicon.ico` you will need to refresh the page in Chrome.

Comment: The html was making a request for CSS file and the page was styled right as it should be. Now that you swapped ROOT for __dirname it is the same. The server gets a request for index.html and then for CSS file, but not for ICO. It is just that browser(Chrome) isn't requesting the icon...

Comment: @MaxSaenko What version of nodejs are you running? I tested my solution under v0.10.25.

Comment: @MaxSaenko Please note that `favicon.ico` gets cached by the browser, so you may not see a request for it in nodejs unless you hard reload on Chrome.

Comment: @MaxSaenko I was able to reproduce the issue in Chrome, and I changed my answer to reflect what I think the problem is, and how to solve it.

Comment: @MaxSaenko Thanks. Check out my new answer, and if it still doesn't work, I'll try to see if I can reproduce the issue using nodejs v0.12.7.

Comment: @MaxSaenko Actually I may have answered too soon. I think that `favicon.ico` gets special treatment, and even if the cache is disabled, no request is made unless the page is explicitly refreshed.

Comment: Yes, thank you very much. Clearing the cache solved the problem completely ^^